# Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of matrix $A$ and $B$, then it is an eigenvalue of $B^{-1}AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I was not too sure how to complete this proof. I thought maybe it was related to $B^{-1}AB$ being the diagonalization of another matrix $D$. I tried approaching it with the determinant and the definition ($A=\lambda x$, $B=\lambda y$) but to no avail.

Comment: what if $0$ is an eigenvalue of both of them ? $B^{-1}$ doesn't even exist.

Comment: It is not clear whether your teacher was wrong or not; it could be you, or some other misunderstanding.

Comment: -1 for "my teacher wrong". You are a practical joker, are you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need it an eigenvalue of $A $. If $Ax=\lambda x $ and $B $ is invertible, let $v=B^{-1}x $. Then
$$
B^{-1}ABv=B^{-1}Ax=\lambda v.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ and $B^{-1}AB$ are similar, they have the same characteristic polynomial, hence the same eigenvalues.